# Editing GTA: Vice City memory addresses using a DLL/ASI

Tags: c++

I currently have this code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: 
        DWORD address = 0x94AD28; //Ped Pointer
        DWORD offset1 = 0x5F4; //Wanted Pointer
        DWORD offset2 = 0x0; //Wanted Counter
        DWORD newvalue[] = {1200}; //Four Wanted Stars
        HANDLE phandle = NULL;
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)address, (LPVOID) &address, 4, 0);
        address = address + offset1;
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)address, (LPVOID) &address, 4, 0);
        address = address + offset2;
        WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)address, (LPVOID) &newvalue, 4, 0);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Note: The wanted pointer is within the ped pointer block.

Now, i thought this would give the player 4 wanted starts when starting a new game because it worked when I did it in a console, but I've learnt that I need to hook a game function that occurs when the player is loaded and then call my code.

This way the code is called and the memory address is changed when the player is defined.
I also read that you don't use Write/Read/ProcessMemory?

If someone could clear this up and guide me I would highly appreciate it.
I'm a real beginner at this. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Look: first thing, you set phandle to NULL, which is completely wrong. You are trying to write something to memory of process, which is not defined.

As you write asi script, which technically is a DLL, your code will run in gta-vc.exe process, so you can get handle simply like that:

HANDLE phandle = GetCurrentProcess();

Next - the Miles Subsystem of gtavc starts all ASI scripts right after GTA movies. Your code will execute at the moment, when the vice city logo with copyright messages appears and then ends. So, to execute your script, you'll need to:
1) check that user has launched the game (there is an address, that contains 1, when menu is activated and 0 when disactivated. Chech gtamodding.com for that)
2) check that user has pressed some key (check the GetAsyncKeyState function on msdn)

About pointers: the player pointer is always points to address of player's object in CPed class. The object address is dynamic, but pointer to player object is always static in vc.
So, to use the pointer, you need:
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)&address,  somevalue, sizeof(type_of_value),0); //sorry for possible mistakes, I'm on the phone right now, and will correct that, when I get my PC)

Good luck from beginner :) I'm learning asi scripting for vc too